# What is this window["obvInit"] ({...}) doing in a script?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to extract some information from Medium URLs and I notice that each page has the entire post contents stored in JSON format. The content looks like this on the page:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
window["obvInit"]({"value":{"id":"e389ba1d8f57","versionId":"1b74...
```

How do I easily extract this JSON from the page? What does the preface of window["obvInit"] before the JSON mean? Can I call the function obvInit in my Chrome console and get the JSON output somehow?

Comment: It's just a function call, passing an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to the function (`window.obvInit`). This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

What this does is call a function. It's probably (but not necesarrily) been declared like `function obvInit(...){...}` on the global window namespace. Now for your problem: You can easily extract the passed object by overwriting the function like this:

```
var _oldObvInit = window.obvInit;
window.obvInit = function(){
        console.log(arguments[0]); //use this to extract the object
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments[0])); //use this to extract JSON
        return _oldObvInit.apply(window, arguments);
}
```

Put this before the script tag you've posted here and after the declaration of the function obvInit.

A bit context: inside every javascript function there's an implicit variable `arguments` which stores the arguments to the function as an array. And `apply` calls a function, sets the context (`this`) and takes the arguments as an array. Exactly what you need to wrap it.

Comment: How to put it into a script in an externally hosted page?

Comment: Unless you want to do something nasty like XSS, Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey might be worth a look. If user interaction is an option you could also put your code into a bookmarklet and let the user execute it. Timing might be a problem then, though. It's hard to say without knowing more context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a technique known as [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works). Basically, since some older browsers don't have great support for cross-origin AJAX using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), you can insert a `<script>` tag into the page that gets the resource you want, except wrapped like this:

```
functionName({ /* ...data... */ });
```

So it calls a function known as `functionName` with the data as an argument. You would provide this function in your own code before inserting that script, like so:

```
function functionName(data) {
    // use the data
}
```

*`window["obvInit"]()` is equivalent to `window.obvInit()` which is equivalent to calling a function defined as `obvInit` at the global level.*

As scripts are not subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you can now get JSON-like data from any domain that will return it in this format.